# Рисование Bitmap на месте курсора

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть форма, на ней битмап с изображением и есть функция масшатибрования, которая рисует второй битмап, который в два раза больше первого. Мне нужна такая функция: навожу курсор мыши на любое место в первом битмапе (допустим, это большая карта и я навожу на страну), масштабирую и чтобы второй битмап нарисовался так, чтобы курсор остался на том же месте нового большого битмапа (чтобы остался на той же стране, но на большем изображении). Сам битмап находится на пиксербоксе, который находится на панели, автоскролл у панели включён.

Сделал так, но это лишь заставляет битмап начинать рисоваться с места моего курсора, то есть на места курсора появляется лишь левый верхний угол битмапа.

```
        public void MapPicBoxScale_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(MapBitmap, Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y, MapPicBox.Width*2, MapPicBox.Height*2);
        }
```

Comment: потому что ты не расчитал математически оффсет (сьезд) изображения которое рисуешь. Что ты ему говоришь делать (отрисовать на месте курсора), то оно и делает.